# Why does my trigger before insert give error 1054, when I try to insert in the table?

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL so this might be a trivial problem. I have written the following trigger:

```
create trigger mytrigger 
    before insert 
    on bud for each row 

begin 
    set @auktionslut = (select auktionslut from auktion where new.AuktionID = auktion.AuktionID);   
        if datediff(@Auktionslut, Now()) < 0 then 
             set @brugerID = (select BrugerID from bud where new.AuktionID = auktion.AuktionID order by budtid desc limit 1); 

            update auktion set Erauktionslut = 1, Koeberbrugerid = @BrugerID where new.auktionid = auktionid; 


        end if;
end;
    §§ 
    delimiter ;
```

I think I might be using the keyword `new` wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, even though it may be a really newbie question.

I have the following relevant tables:

```
create table Bruger (
BrugerID int,
Navn varchar (255),
Adresse varchar (255),
kodeord varchar (40),
Email varchar (255),
Primary key (BrugerID)
);

create table auktion (
AuktionID int, 
Saelgerbrugerid int,
Koeberbrugerid int,
Samletoprindeligpris float,
Minimumspris float,
Endeligpris float,
Auktionslut datetime,
Produktbeskrivelse varchar (255),
Erauktionslut boolean,
Primary key (AuktionID),
foreign key (saelgerbrugerid) references bruger(brugerid),
foreign key (koeberbrugerid) references bruger(brugerid)
);

create table Bud (
AuktionID int,
BrugerID int,
Budpris int,
Budtid datetime,
primary key (brugerid,auktionid),
foreign key (brugerid) references bruger(brugerid),
foreign key (auktionid) references auktion(auktionid)
);
```

When trying to insert this into the tables:

I get:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'auktion.AuktionID' in 'where clause'

Comment: `from bud where new.AuktionID = auktion.AuktionID` - maybe you mean `from bud where new.AuktionID = bud.AuktionID`

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i needed